# try to render data from 2 different source using .map() function

Tags: reactjs

I try to render data that match each other from 2 database 
by mount data with

```
//mount data from database
const { items } = this.props.item;
const { stocks } = this.props.stock;
```

I try to show data in one table like

```
name of stock | stock detail
    code1     | detailcode1
    code2     | detailcode2
    code3     | detailcode3
```

with code like

```
{items.map(({ stockCode }) => (<td>{stockCode}</td>)
{stocks.map(({ stockCode,detail }) => (<td>{detail}</td>)
```

I want to create function like 
"if stockCode name from database1 match database2 then show detail"

anyone have idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While @WillJenkins answer works, I don't like the idea of re-computing the matches with every re-render of the component. If you're data is changing, it might be an okay option, but since you stated that you get this data from a database, I assume that it doesn't change.

In that case it might be good to only check if the `stock_code` of an entry in `stocks` is in `items` once after loading the data:

```
// after the data was loaded (NOT in the render method):
for (const stock of stocks) {
    const item = items.find(i => i.stock_code === stock.stock_code);

    if (item === undefined) continue;

    stock.item = item;
}

// in the table body (render method)
stocks.map(stock => {
    const { item } = stock;

    return (
        <tr>
            <td>{stock.stock_code}</td>
            <td>{stock.stock_name}</td>
            <td>{item && item.item_name}</td>
            <td>{item && item.item_price}</td>
        </tr>
    );
})
```

I quickly coded an example you can check out [here](https://codesandbox.io/embed/interesting-mclaren-6cn4w).

Answer (score 2):

You can just use one `.map` and conditionally render the row :

```
{stocks.map(({ stockCode, detail }) =>
    items.some(({ stockCode: itemCode }) => stockCode === itemCode) ? (
        <tr>
            <td>{stockCode}</td>
            <td>{detail}</td>
        </tr>
    ) : null
)}
```

Alternatively, if performance is a concern you could create a [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) with stockCode as `key` and detail as the `value`. Then `.map` over your items array pulling matching values out of your Map.

Comment: While this might work, I'm not a fan of it personally. Calling `includes` (now `some`) with every re-render doesn't seem too great performance wise.

Comment: "Doesn't seem too great" doesn't seem very quantitative 

Comment: I don't have a performance measure at hand of course, but this is clearly a one time operation, where you would check once if the item is present in the second array and remember if it was or not. Searching the second array for every item in the first array with every re-render just doesn't make sense.

Comment: If the props don't change and the component stays mounted then it will be a one time operation. If the data changes then it will need to be re-rendered.

Comment: Since he gets his data from a database and I assume it's not a real-time database, it's unlikely that the data will change.

Comment: How about if I want to show more detail about items too? how to mount it to show. For example I want to show itemCodeDetail1 and itemCodeDetail2 in the table too.

Comment: @koh do you mean there are multiple details for one item?

Comment: @TobiasTengler yes, is it possible to show multiple info from item and stock ex show item_name, item_price, stock_name and stock_code at the same time with condition item_name === stock_code

Comment: @koh you mean in the same table multiple details columns?

Comment: @TobiasTengler yes

Comment: @koh I updated my answer. Is this what you're looking for? Otherwise please be more concrete with your question / requirements.